Define `minted` style via one command
To factorize one of my code, I would like to define minted style using a command, but the following code fails.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[highlightmode = immediate]{minted}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}
               
\newcommand{\mystyle}{vs}
\newmintinline[mylatex]{latex}{style = \mystyle}

\tcbset{
  mylistingstyle/.style = {
    minted language = latex,
    minted style = #1
  },
}


\newtcblisting{mylatexenv}{%
  mylistingstyle = \mystyle
}

\begin{document}

\mylatex{$\LaTeX = B + C$}

\begin{mylatexenv}
$A = B + C$
    
\begin{equation}
  A(x)^2 = C(x,y)
\end{equation}
\end{mylatexenv}

\end{document}

Here is the error emitted for the macro, but the environment also fails.
Package minted Error: Highlighting style is set to "vs" 
but only style names with alphanumeric characters, hyphens, 
and underscores are supported; falling back to default style.


Do you need to alter \mystyle later on?

I use a system of themes: each theme will set its own style.

And each theme will alter the definition of \mystyle? Also should multiple themes be applicable during the same run or is it set once and should then be in effect for the entire current document?

One theme for the whole run and for the whole document.

Skillmon's answer works perfectly well, but I'll add that since v3.0, minted uses pgfkeys too. So \newmintinline[mylatex]{latex}{style/.expand once=\mystyle} does what you want.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[highlightmode = immediate]{minted}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}
               
\newcommand{\mystyle}{vs}
\newmintinline[mylatex]{latex}{style/.expand once = \mystyle}

\tcbset{
  mylistingstyle/.style = {
    minted language = latex,
    minted style = #1
  },
}

\newtcblisting{mylatexenv}{%
  mylistingstyle/.expand once = \mystyle
}

\begin{document}

\mylatex{$\LaTeX = B + C$}

\begin{mylatexenv}
$A = B + C$
    
\begin{equation}
  A(x)^2 = C(x,y)
\end{equation}
\end{mylatexenv}

\end{document}



If you don't need to alter the definition of \mystyle after you set \newmintinline you can simply get what you want by expanding the contents of that macro. In the options of tcolorbox you can use the .expand once handler provided by pgfkeys, for \newmintinline you can use \expanded like in the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[highlightmode = immediate]{minted}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}
               
\newcommand{\mystyle}{vs}
\expanded{\noexpand\newmintinline[mylatex]{latex}
  {style = {\unexpanded\expandafter{\mystyle}}}}

\tcbset{
  mylistingstyle/.style = {
    minted language = latex,
    minted style = #1
  },
}


\newtcblisting{mylatexenv}{%
  mylistingstyle/.expand once = \mystyle
}

\begin{document}

\mylatex{$\LaTeX = B + C$}

\begin{mylatexenv}
$A = B + C$
    
\begin{equation}
  A(x)^2 = C(x,y)
\end{equation}
\end{mylatexenv}

\end{document}


A bit of explanation: \expanded expands its argument fully like \message would do and is itself expandable (you can also compare this to \edef, with the very peculiar difference that you don't need to double # inside of \expanded). \noexpand simply says that the next single token shouldn't expand. \unexpanded\expandafter{<stuff>} is an idiom to expand the first (and in this case only) token of <stuff> once (that's what \expandafter does) and protecting it from further expanding (that's what \unexpanded does, in addition to it expanding the \expandafter since it's searching for the opening brace).

This does the job. Thanks a lot! Can you explain a little how the \expand macro and its friends work here?

@projetmbc done, I hope this suffices, if not feel free to ask.

Very clear! Thanks again.

@Skillmon minted 3.0 uses pgfkeys so \newmintinline[mylatex]{latex}{style/.expand once=\mystyle} works too

@mbert ooh, I didn't know that, you might want to post a better answer :)

As the use of bridges à la \expand is instructive, I think it would be useful to update the answer without deleting the first version.
